# Dynamically adding file upload controls gives error

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to follow this guide to create file upload controls dynamically.

http://humrahimcs.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/dynamically-create-multiple-file-upload-control-with-asp-net-c/

But when I finally get to submitting my form, I get a connection reset error without any more information. What am I doing wrong?

```
    function AddNewRow() {

        var rownum = 1;

        var div = document.createElement("div");

        var divid= "dv" + rownum;

        div.setAttribute("ID",divid);

        rownum++;

        var lbl = document.createElement("label");

        lbl.setAttribute("ID", "lbl" + rownum);

        lbl.setAttribute("class", "label1");

        lbl.innerHTML = "Imagen: ";

        rownum++;

        var _upload = document.createElement("input");

        _upload.setAttribute("type", "file");

        _upload.setAttribute("ID", "upload" + rownum);

        _upload.setAttribute("runat", "server");

        _upload.setAttribute("name","uploads"+rownum)

        rownum++;

        var hyp = document.createElement("a");

        hyp.setAttribute("style", "cursor:Pointer");

        hyp.setAttribute("onclick", "return RemoveDv('" + divid + "');");

        hyp.innerHTML = "Remover";

        rownum++;

        var br=document.createElement("br");

        var _pdiv = document.getElementById("Parent");

        div.appendChild(br);

        div.appendChild(lbl);

        div.appendChild(_upload);

        div.appendChild(hyp);

        _pdiv.appendChild(div);

    }

    function RemoveDv(obj) {

        var p = document.getElementById("Parent");

        var chld = document.getElementById(obj);

        p.removeChild(chld);

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Try this link : http://forums.asp.net/t/1417476.aspx/3/10 OR also refer this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Uploading-Multiple-Files-using-JavaScript-Dynamic-FileUpload-Controls-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: Yes, that just did it! Thank you very much.